# uninstall Mongodb Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb

We have uninstalled the mongodb but its showing in info.php file.

How we can remove it permanantly from server. in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extension.

In your php.ini file you probably still have this (manually added) line:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

And you need to remove the mod from php with something like ...

```
phpdismod mongodb
```

Comment: And you need to remove the mod from php with something like ...

phpdismod mongodb

Comment: Thanks for the reply what about the above one where i have to remove 'phpdismod mongodb'

Comment: Linux command line.